# !! used in node ? will this check undefined in node and array length and empty Object in what all cases can this be used for

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i came across this code recently in node. but i cant find a good understanding on where to use this.

I want data to be not undefined, not 0 and not empty array.

```
 if(!!data){
    do something ...
 }
```

It proves working fine for empty array value = 0, etc can someone explain in detail about this.

```
if ( typeof data !== 'undefined'){ do something }

if ( data !== null ){ do something }
```

I have tried to implement this and it failed when i send an undefined variable. 
the feature can be used to full extend if it can be shared to everyone.

Comment: Is this question related to ``node.js or python``

Answer (score 1):

this is just pure js. Double NOT operator "!!". So the first ! coerce the value to a boolean and inverse it, then the second ! reverses it to the original boolean equivalent. So basically converts nonboolean to boolean

Answer (score 0):

Array length will not be considered. Empty arrays will be avoided. Empty String  will be checked. Any value 0 will be considered false and other integers will be considered true. Lets look at all these examples and figure out the usage.

```
let a = 0 ;
console.log(!!a) //false

a = "";
console.log(!!a) //false

a = " ";
console.log(!!a) // true since a has a space value 
console.log(!!a.trim())//false

a = undefined
console.log(!!a) //false

a= {}
console.log(a) // true Use Object.keys(a).length > 0 to check empty object or 
               // use _.isEmpty(a) for checking empty object

a = { name:"Rahul"}
console.log(a) // true 

a = []
console.log(a) // true Use array.length > 0 to check empty array 

a = [1,2,3]
console.log(a) // true
```